# unable to compare screen values with sql table value

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to compare the screen values input against the value stored in DB. Currently i am trying this code:

```
cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2);
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://madison-dev.czr6vej2htnn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/madisondb","madisonadmin","t4xuw94$");// + "databasename=madison-dev.czr6vej2htnn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet Rs = st.executeQuery("select name, zipcode, state, city, street from business_master where user_id =(\r\n" + 
    "select id\r\n" + 
    "from user_master\r\n" + 
    "where email = 'cell.getStringCellValue()') \r\n");

while (Rs.next()) {
    //  System.out.println(Rs.getString(1) + "  " + Rs.getString(2) + "  " + Rs.getString(3) + "  "
    //  + Rs.getString(4) + "  " + Rs.getString(5));
    System.out.println(Rs.getString(0));
}
```

The screen is not showing any values.. and when i am trying to print `System.out.println(Rs.getString(3))` outside of the loop it gives me an error

> java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Selenium.

Comment: I'm not good in Sql but try to check the size of your ResultSet, if the size is 0 then you are trying to retrieve information on an empty set

Comment: thanks @HamzaTorjmen

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find all the rows where the email address is literally the text `'cell.getStringCellValue()'` rather than the value returned by that method.

Whilst you code assemble your query string, that lays you open to SQL injection attacks. Use a prepared statement instead

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(
    "select name, zipcode, state, city, street from business_master where user_id =(" + 
    "select id " + 
    "from user_master " + 
    "where email = ?)");
st.setString(1, cell.getStringCellValue());
ResultSet Rs = st.executeQuery();
```